# Cannot use inheritance properly Ionic 2

Tags: angular, inheritance, typescript, ionic2, extends

I am working on an app with different pages and I wanted to have an abstract class for the page from which all the pages inherit from.
The problem is if I "extend" one class with the abstract one, it works, but as soon as I two or more pages extend the abstract class it gives me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

**My AbstractPage is this one:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Contact } from '../contact/contact';
import { Page1 } from '../page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../page2/page2';
import { Page3 } from '../page3/page3';
import { Page4 } from '../page4/page4';
import { Page5 } from '../page5/page5';
import { Page6 } from '../page6/page6';
import { Page7 } from '../page7/page7';
import { Page8 } from '../page8/page8';
import { Page9 } from '../page9/page9';
import { Page10 } from '../page10/page10';
import { Page11 } from '../page11/page11';
import { Page12 } from '../page12/page12';
import { Page13 } from '../page13/page13';
import { Page14 } from '../page14/page14';
import { Page15 } from '../page15/page15';
import { Page16 } from '../page16/page16';

export abstract class AbstractPage {
  static pages = [Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5, Page6, Page7, Page8, Page9, Page10, Page11, Page12, Page13, Page14, Page15, Page16];
  pageNumber: number;
  hasSharableContent: boolean;
  public navCtrl: NavController;

  constructor( page_number: number, has_sharable_content: boolean) {
    this.pageNumber = page_number;
    this.hasSharableContent = has_sharable_content;
  }

  changePage(direction: number) {
    if (direction==1){
      console.log(direction,this.pageNumber);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(AbstractPage.pages[this.pageNumber], {}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'});
    }
    else if(direction == 2){
      this.navCtrl.push(Contact);
    }
    else{
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(AbstractPage.pages[this.pageNumber-1], {}, {animate: true, direction: 'back'});
    }
  }
}
```

**My Page1 is:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AbstractPage } from '../abstract-page/abstract-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})

export class Page1 extends AbstractPage{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    super(1, false);
  }
}
```

**My Page2 is:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AbstractPage } from '../abstract-page/abstract-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})


export class Page2 extends AbstractPage{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    super(2, true);
  }
}
```

**I've added a repo on GitHub if someone wants to try and solve the problem**:
https://github.com/francescobenintende/Tests/tree/master/abstraction

**Error**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLaG4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can't use this kind of Page component inheritance with Ionic2 and Typescript now.Hope you can do that with Ionic3 and latest Typescript which will be included with Ionic3.This issue is related to the Typescript and web pack.

You can get [**more info here**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-when-extends-in-typescript/53869).

You too can see the issue here if you explore the `main.js.map` file.It creates a subclass(`Page1`) first and after that base class (`AbstractPage`).That is the reason for this error.But unfortunately, we cannot change the order.

**Old Answer:**

You can try with `public` `constructor()` on the `abstract` class as shown below.

```
 export abstract class AbstractPage {


  constructor(public page_number: number,public has_sharable_content: boolean) {

    }

  changePage(direction: number) {
    if (direction==1){
      console.log(direction,this.page_number);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(AbstractPage.pages[this.page_number], {}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'});
    }
    else if(direction == 2){
      this.navCtrl.push(Contact);
    }
    else{
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(AbstractPage.pages[this.page_number-1], {}, {animate: true, direction: 'back'});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used above configuration with my app and no problem at all.It seems the different issue.remove all the code of the fault class(subclass) and just do simple inheritance and check.

Comment: What do you mean by simple inheritance?

Comment: I mean just remove all the code on that class(subclass) and check.Like this.Hope you have more code on this class.`export class Page2 extends AbstractPage{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    super(2, true);
  }
}`

Comment: I removed everything from the class except what I posted in the initial question.

Comment: can you create a lightweight version of this use case and put that on git repo? Then we can play with it no?

Comment: Ok I'm gonna modify the initial question and include the link.

Comment: please see the **Error** section of your post above.

Comment: Now can I run your Git project? is `ionic serve` working on git project which you have shared with us?

Comment: You can download download the repo from this [link](https://github.com/francescobenintende/Tests) , extract that, then after navigating into the `abstraction` folder run the `npm install` and then `ionic serve` it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, at least now I know it's Typescript.

Comment: Yep, Hope Ionic3 will not have this issue hence it'll use latest typescript version.Hope You can close this post now no? see how to do that:http://stackoverflow.com/tour